# "iPhone Developer" vs. provisioning profile code signing identity

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

For "Code Signing Identity" for a build configuration, I have a choice between "iPhone Developer" and a specific identity that is found in the ad-hoc provisioning profile assigned to that configuration.

What is the difference between the two? Should I explicitly assign the identity from the assigned provisioning profile, or should I leave it at "iPhone Developer"? I currently have it at "iPhone Developer" and the app is installing OK on the designated devices.

After reading a [possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583968/signing-ios-app-as-iphone-developer), it looks like "iPhone Developer" makes Xcode choose the signing identity automatically. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. As long as You don't have more than one identity with a particular Bundle ID it will work correctly.

Comment: what to do if there is more than one identity?

Comment: Actually I believe you can’t register the same bundle ID in 2 different accounts.

Comment: In the manual option i can see two profiles, one my developer and another distribution of whole team, so in confusion which one to choose for release mode?

Comment: It all depends on your particular setup really, but for the release you should use distribution, not development.